# Generic in custom page (XAML)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an issue into Xamarin and I have found similar issue on Xamarin forum. here it is, [enter link description here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/33750/generic-in-custom-page-xaml). But I didn't get any solution for this. Can anyone help me for this issue.

Another Forum link is: [Another Xamarin forum link](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21470/generic-base-class-for-a-custom-contentpage#latest)

-- Update

Here is the autogenerated code

```
namespace MyDemo.App.Views {
    using System;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;


    public partial class SignInView : global::MyDemo.App.Views.BaseView {

        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")]
        private void InitializeComponent() {
            this.LoadFromXaml(typeof(SignInView));
        }
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, I would suggest you to use:

```
public class SomePage : SomeGenericPage<SomeViewModel> { }

public partial class SomeAnotherPage : SomePage
{
    public SomeAnotherPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

My `SomePage` has generic `T` property `ViewModel` and then I could reach it from `SomeAnotherPage`. `ViewModel` property will have type `SomeViewModel`.

```
public class SomeGenericPage<T> : ContentPage where T : SomeBaseViewModel, new()
{
    readonly T _viewModel;
    public T ViewModel => _viewModel;

    public SomeGenericPage()
    {
        _viewModel = new T();
        BindingContext = _viewModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Egor,
But here in my case. 
public sealed partial class SignInView : BaseView<SignInController>, ISignInView
    {  // Some code here 
    }

May be this issue is generated because of xaml markup. But I am getting any idea how to resolve it.

Comment: Could you add your code to question to make it more readable?